# RHEL7 показывает знаки вопроса вместо прав доступа

Tags: linux, unix, centos, rhel

непонятно почему консоль RHEL7 показывает ???????? вместо прав доступа

как видим, пользователь - владелец, и имеет доступ к папке, но не может увидеть нормально права. также не может "зайти" в папку. 
root все нормально видит и все может.

если выдать 777 на папку, то проблема исчезает

```
[dm@app524 ~]$ ll
total 210004
drw-rw-rw-  4 dm dm  4096 Jul 21 15:12 config 
[dm@app524 ~]$ ll config/
ls: cannot access config/dm-notification.yml: Permission denied
ls: cannot access config/dm-dynamics.yml: Permission denied
ls: cannot access config/security: Permission denied
ls: cannot access config/dm-admin-api.yml: Permission denied
ls: cannot access config/dm-otp.yml: Permission denied
ls: cannot access config/dm-db-app.yml: Permission denied
ls: cannot access config/attachments: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? attachments
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dm-admin-api.yml
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dm-db-app.yml
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dm-dynamics.yml
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dm-notification.yml
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dm-otp.yml
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? security
[dm@app524 ~]$ cd config/
-bash: cd: config/: Permission denied
[dm@app524 ~]$ sudo -s
[root@app524 dm]# ll config/
total 28
drw-rw-rw- 2 dm dm 4096 Jul 21 15:12 attachments
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dm dm  139 Jul 21 15:12 dm-admin-api.yml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dm dm  129 Jul 21 15:12 dm-db-app.yml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dm dm  232 Jul 21 15:12 dm-dynamics.yml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dm dm  407 Jul 21 15:12 dm-notification.yml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dm dm  104 Jul 21 15:12 dm-otp.yml
drw-rw-rw- 2 dm dm 4096 Jul 21 15:12 security
```

Comment: На каталоге `config` есть права на чтение, но нет прав на вход в каталог (`x`) список файлов вы получаете, а информацию о них не можете.

Comment: @Mike это какие-то особые права?

Comment: почему особые. обыкновенные. для обычных файлов 'x' разрешение на выполнение, а для каталогов оно означает разрешение на 'вход'

Comment: @Mike оформите ответ.

Comment: исправил в вопросе: это не "маска прав доступа". это **и есть** права доступа. "маска" - это про несколько иное.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы правы. спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [документации](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Mode-Structure.html) (доступна локально командой `$ info "File permissions" "Mode Structure"`):

> There are three kinds of permissions that a user can have for a file:
>   ...
>   3. permission to execute the file (run it as a program).  For directories, this means permission to access files in the directory.

вольный перевод:

> существует три вида разрешений, которые может иметь пользователь для файла:
>   ...
>   3. разрешение на выполнение файла (запуск его как программы). для каталогов это означает разрешение на доступ к файлам в этом каталоге.

---

отображается это разрешение буквой `x`. например, у каталога `/` это разрешение установлено для всех трёх категорий пользователей: владельца, группы и всех остальных.

```
$ ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Jul 21 21:05 /
```

добавить это разрешение для владельца файла/каталога:

```
$ chmod u+x файл-или-каталог
```